# Running a command from a command line tool from another app in django

Tags: django

I am building a Webapp using Django and want to generate some comments from a command-line tool present in the same directory as the web app. What are the different methods to call this tool from the web app and run commands in the terminal and extract output from it and display it in a web app?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please explain carefully what you wish to do.  Do you mean you want to have the web app run a command locally and the results be displayed to the web app?  If so, you could have the webapp use ```subprocess``` to and use the output from that to display to the ui.  (Not suggested, as it's potentially a security issue...)

Comment: nice wish @ewong :p

Comment: @TanveerAhmad  ;P

Comment: I want to run the command in a separate command-line tool utility that I have opened in Django so I want to find a way through which I can run a specific command like python ./config.py init -nr in this tool and extract output and display it in web app which is a different project in Django. @ewong

Comment: @lucidcm read my comment.  Read up on python's ```subprocess``` module. Then take the results from the subprocess.Popen() (or check_output) and display it.    Since you haven't specified much in terms of code, that's all I can do.